# Graphviz: how to give same rank to nodes in different clusters

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm trying to give two nodes inside two different cluster the same rank, in order to make dot show them at the same level. In particular in this example I would like node a4 and b3 to be at the same level. 
This is the code:

```
digraph G {
    subgraph cluster_0 {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        a0 -> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4;
        label = "process #1";
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        node [style=filled];
        b0 -> b1 -> b2 -> b3;
        label = "process #2";
        color=blue
    }

    start -> a0;
    start -> b0;
    a1 -> b3;
    b2 -> a3;
    a4 -> end;
    b3 -> end;

//  {rank=same; a4; b3;}

    start [shape=Mdiamond];
    end [shape=Msquare];
}
```

I tried adding the line `{rank=same; a4; b3;}`, but this just messes up the clusters because removes the nodes a4 and b3 from their respective clusters. I also tried to add invisible nodes, but they also modify the clusters in the wrong way.
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you want to skip a level in your `b` cluster; you only can do so by introducing an invisible node the right way. I hope I got your point right with this code:

```
digraph G {
    start[ shape=Mdiamond ];
    end[ shape=Msquare ];
    bx[ shape = point, width = 0.01 ];      // invisible node

    subgraph cluster_0 {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        a0 -> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4;
        label = "process #1";
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        node [style=filled];
        b0 -> b1;
        b1 -> b2;
        b2 -> bx[ dir = none ];          // connecting inv node without arrow
        bx -> b3;                        // continue normally
        label = "process #2";
        color=blue
    }

    start -> a0;
    start -> b0;
    a1 -> b3;
    b2 -> a3;

    a4 -> end;
    b3 -> end;
}
```

which gives you

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted, even if is a bit cumbersome.